# Maya adding guide produces the no bound geometry for error

Tags: maya

I am receiving an error whenever I try to add a guide to the hair cap that is parented by the G8M figure. If I select the G8M and create a new description, then I do not have this error.

I have spent over two hours trying to add one single guide to a hair cap and, while I have found a work around, I want to understand why.

Some more background:
I have used the Cleanup tool. Frankly I have tried everything, including selecting almost all the options, which the cap will display as a blue color - I believe that means no errors or this has been cleaned. Yet, I am unable to use the hair cap.

On one of the Japanese forums, I used a suggestion to unparent the cap, duplicate it, then use xgen, which did work, but I want to know why?

Why does duplicating a geometry, work for binding to xgen? And why picking any other geometry will work, but not the original hair cap geometry?

[image: no bound geometry]
[image: duplicate geometry allowed to have guides]

BTW, I did try just unparenting the hair cap, but that did not work. I had to duplicate it, then xgen would allow the newly created/duplicated geometry to be bound.